# KeyError: ‘test’ when trying to divide a custom dataset into train and test for fine-tuning

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

So, I am trying to fine-tune a Protbert Transformers with a .fasta file I have converted into a CSV. I have been following this hugging face [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training).

Everything goes fine until I get to the training section. I have uploaded the CSV with the sequences but when I try to create small datasets for training and testing as they say in the tutorial I get: `KeyError: 'test'`. It is strange because it doesn’t say anything else. Therefore, I can’t continue with the tutorial to fine-tune the model.

The code I have for now:

```
dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files='/content/sequences.csv')

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("Rostlab/prot_bert", do_lower_case=False )

def tokenize_function(samples):
   return tokenizer(samples["Protein Sequence"], padding="max_length", truncation=True)

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

small_train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))
small_eval_dataset = tokenized_datasets["test"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000)) #Here is where I get the error.

#I can't continue with this part because of the error.
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab 
Notebooks/test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch")

metric = load_metric("accuracy")

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

trainer = Trainer(
   model=model,
   args=training_args,
   train_dataset=small_train_dataset,
   eval_dataset=small_eval_dataset,
   compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
 )

 trainer.train()
```

Comment: as the error message, there is no `"test"` argument in tokenized_datasets, can you check the `sequences.csv` if it splites dataset to train and test?

Comment: The sequences.csv is a CSV that has two columns, one for the IDs and one for the Sequences, there is no train nor test. However, it works for the train line but not for the test one

Comment: I found the code of [datasets package](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/blob/main/src/datasets/load.py), as they write in there, it's able to read the dataset from [this list](https://huggingface.co/datasets) only, can you try again with any dataset in there?